# interacting with ggmap in Shiny: can the user zoom, scroll, etc

Tags: r, google-maps, shiny

Like many of us, I'm spoiled from using Google Maps -- I'm used to clicking and dragging the map to recenter, or zooming in/out according to my every whim.

So when I started playing with ggmaps in Shiny, I suppose I expected the same functionality.

In my sample Shiny I'm working with, I can generate the map nicely and it looks fine, but after it is generated, is there no way for the user to click and recenter, or zoom in / out? In other words, is can I harness some of the basic google map properties in any way? And if not, is there a different map package that may have some of this?

[image]

**EDIT**

The comment from Scott Chamberlain was enough to send me on the right direction:
*See the leaflet package by rstudio github.com/rstudio/leaflet*

Comment: See the `leaflet` package by rstudio https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit old, but I still want to point out that adding interactivity to ggmaps output is definitely possible, since it is a ggplot2 object. Shiny has inherent interactive tool functions that record coordinates on the ggplot2 object (click, dblclick, hover, and brush). With a bit of work, these recorded coordinates could be used to recenter the map, zoom in on a location, zoom out, etc.

At the end of the day, it won't be as interactive as maps like Google and leaflet, but the ggmap/ggplot2 package(s) allow for more layer options in my opinion.

If you have any interest in making a ggmap interactive, feel free to message me. (Don't want to type up an example that no one will look at).

Answer (score 2):

With my `googleway` package you can now plot an interactive Google Map

```
library(shiny)
library(googleway)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(),
        mainPanel(
            google_mapOutput(outputId = "myMap")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output){

    # mapKey <- 'your_api_key'
    output$myMap <- renderGoogle_map({
        google_map(key = mapKey)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the example gallery for shiny is a [superzip](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html) example that includes an interactive map.  The shiny source code is available that you could work from.

I don't think that it uses ggmap though.

The [basic plot interaction demo](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-basic.html) on the same gallary page, does show an example using ggplot2 graphics and shows how you can identify click location, selection information, etc.  You could use that information to create many of the same tools that you are looking for (add the symbols in the corner and when someone clicks on the graph, figure which symbol is closest to the click and update the graph accordingly).